# Authorize.net Recurring Transactions (ARB) - Silent Post URL Not Working

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, authorize.net

We are on CiviCRM 4.7.21. and Drupal. We have entered the proper Silent Post URL in Authorize.net for CiviCRM 4.7 which is "Drupal: https://yoursite.org/civicrm/payment/ipn/2".  I have the correct payment processor ID.  However, CiviCRM is not getting updated and the transaction status is Pending.  The Recurring transaction gets setup properly in Authorize.net and works fine.

We initially tested this in CiviCRM version 4.6 and it all worked fine.  The Silent Post URL as a different syntax.  We have tried both the old and new version for the Silent Post URL and it does not work.

Is there something else I am missing?

Below are log messages related to the contribution transaction;

```
"Notice: Undefined index: payment_processor_type_id in CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPayment() (line 248 of /srv/www/resolute/nc.resoluteroots.com/sites/all/modules/civ‌​icrm/CRM/Financial/B‌​AO/PaymentProcessor.‌​php)." 

"Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPayment() (line 249 of /srv/www/resolute/nc.resoluteroots.com/sites/all/modules/civ‌​icrm/CRM/Financial/B‌​AO/PaymentProcessor.‌​php)."
```

Comment: Have you checked your logs to see if the information is making it back to Civi at all?  We've occasionally seen situations where the info can be found in the log, which at least indicates Civi received it from A.net.

Comment: Yes, I do have some log messages -                                                         "Notice: Undefined index: payment_processor_type_id in CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPayment() (line 248 of /srv/www/resolute/nc.resoluteroots.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php)."                                    "Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPayment() (line 249 of /srv/www/resolute/nc.resoluteroots.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php)."

Comment: maybe add above in your original question

Comment: Possibly relevant: [CRM-16928: Auth.net URLs changed](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16928), [CRM-20880: Issues with credit cards on Auth.net](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20880).